# Why getUserMedia() showing permission denied error in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, permission-denied, getusermedia

I am using getUserMedia() for video streaming in node.js and angular project(MEAN). My `<video>` tag is inside partial file. This project is running smoothly & compatible in Google Chrome, Opera and Firefox in local server. But when I am trying to run it over Ubuntu server using Google Chrome (only problem with Chrome), video is not showing.
 Error details in console as follows:

(program):84 navigator.getUserMedia error:  PermissionDeniedError(error name)

I am using chrome version 47.0.2526.80 .I am using http for this project. I am also getting warning to switching my application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. Why it is not running properly in Chrome.

Comment: ubuntu has its own browser chromium did you check in chromium

Comment: Be more specific, show your code please.

Comment: Deprecated: navigator.getUserMedia:
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time. @Rajib

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome has stopped supporting `getUserMedia()` along with some other features like `Geolocation`, `Fullscreen` etc. on insecure origins. I think it allows these features for localhost in order to enable testing but they won't work on an actual server.

Here is the related announcement from google:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Comment: if i make my server https will that solve this issue

Comment: yes, from now on it has become mandatory to deploy on secure servers if you use those API

Comment: yes you will need https support for your live servers from now on as @beaver stated.