# WebRTC not displaying video in Chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, video, webrtc

I`m trying to use Web RTC. It works fine in EDGE,but when  im trying open it in chrome\firefox it is just displays a white screen ( no video loaded).
I tried to open some of this samples https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

**SOLVED**:
Skype in the background block my camera somehow

Answer (score 0):

I only see that (in Chrome or Firefox) if the access to the devices has not been granted:

> Permissions have not been granted to use your camera and microphone, you need to allow the page access to your devices in order for the demo to work.

```
getUserMedia error: PermissionDeniedError
```

And the problem is that those scripts rely on `getUserMedia()`, which was deprecated (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178254) and [this annoucement](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins))

The OP confirms the permission could not be granted because another software was preempting the camera:

> Skype in the background block my camera somehow

Comment: I didn`t get this error. I grant permissions.
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ 
this sample show this message in console  :
Got stream with constraints: Object
main.js:23 Using video device: HP HD Webcam [Fixed] (04f2:b370)
Seems to be this problem related to by pc,cause it works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? What version of chrome or Firefox are you using?

Comment: win10 pro, Chrome  55.0.2883.87 m and FF 50.0.2

Comment: Same here. what about trying it in a private session?

Comment: Nothing change.. Chrome shows me icon,that website is currently using my camera,but camera`s led didn`t start shining

Comment: Strange, there must a policy in place blocking access to this device.

Comment: @blckt Good catch with Skype: I suppose this is why you could not grant permission in Firefox/Chrome: Skype was preempting the camera. I have edited the answer for more visibility.